# Modify timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a timestamp like `2014-08-17T06:16:55.967Z` that I want to insert in a Postgres db, but I want to remove just the milliseconds and keep the 'T' and the 'Z'. Anyone know how that is possible? I've tried `2014-08-17T06:16:55.967Z::timestamp(0)` or `timestamptz(0)`, but they both take away what I want to keep.

I would like `2014-08-17T06:16:55Z`.

Comment: so you want `...16:55.000Z` basically? or `...16:55Z`?

Comment: Yeah, I've should've clarified, basically ...16:55Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_trunc`

```
select date_trunc('second', '2014-08-17T06:16:55.967Z'::timestamp);
     date_trunc      
---------------------
 2014-08-17 06:16:55
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

The `T` and `Z` in the input string are not saved in the timestamp column. If you want to show them then format the output

```
select to_char(
    date_trunc('second', '2014-08-17T06:16:55.967Z'::timestamp),
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSZ'
);
       to_char        
----------------------
 2014-08-17T06:16:55Z
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: yeah, but that does not satisfy what I want because it removes the T and Z which I'd like to keep